# copy DataGridView to another DataGridView with all colors, Cell formating etc

Tags: c#, datagridview, colors, copy

I have a question about DataGridviews. I want to copy the DGV1 to DGV2 with all values, colors and ErrorText. Is that possible to do it?

I did with something like this:

```
dataGridView3.DataSource = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource
```

but this solution copy just the values. I want to have all color, ErrorText etc. like the Original one. Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/3473722/1080742

Answer (score 0):

You really cant do this easily. (See this discussion here: [Cloning a GUI component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589149/cloning-a-gui-component)) There are various object cloning methods out there but they require ISerializable or ICloneable to work, both of which DataGridView does not implement.  You could also try an object mapping library like  [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)
.